# trying to use a condition inside map in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dictionary, semantic-ui

I am trying to display data to the table from my database using api, but I want to limit the data to a certain number example if I get 10 table columns, I want to display only 5. Here is a peice of code for my map function:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Icon, Table, Menu, Select, Form,Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const CustomerTable = (props) => {
    const{customer}=props;

  
    var leng=5;
    
    
    return(
 <div style={{marginTop:'15px'}}>
  <Table celled striped>
    <Table.Header>
      <Table.Row>
      <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
        <Table.HeaderCell>Address</Table.HeaderCell>
        <Table.HeaderCell>Actions</Table.HeaderCell>
        <Table.HeaderCell>Actions</Table.HeaderCell>
      </Table.Row>
    </Table.Header>
      
    <Table.Body > 
    {customer.map((c) => {
      return(
      <Table.Row key={c.id}>
        <Table.Cell>{c.name}</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>{c.address}</Table.Cell>
         <Table.Cell>
            <Button color="red">Delete</Button>
         </Table.Cell>
         <Table.Cell>
            <Button color="red">Edit</Button>
        </Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>

    )})}
            )

    </Table.Body>

  </Table>

 
</div>
    )
}

export default CustomerTable;
```

I tried if else condition (trying to get .length) but it doesnt work as I input the customer data as a prop from my other class. Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Is this the whole file? because I am getting syntax errors, and I would say try to format the code in a more readable manner if you can. You will get more answers.

Comment: Hi, there is another file named customer where  I am fetching the data from database which is a localhost, hence it might not work in there.

Comment: i dont know if i fully get the question.. do you want to limit the columns or the rows? if the rows then you could just to the conditional higher up before the map

Comment: `const visibleCustomers = customers.lengh > 5 ? customers.slice(0,5) : customers`

then you just map over visibleCustomers

Comment: Hi john, I am not able to use customers.length function as its a prop from my another class.

Comment: you should still have access to is as it's getting passed down to your react component. it should just be a simple array, nothing overly special with it

Comment: You don't need to test the length, use `slice(0, leng)`.

Comment: ah, good catch @norie. I always forget the intricacies of slice

Comment: Hy norie, thanks very much, it worked!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you know the condition before iterate you can slice the array.

```
<Table.Body > 

{/* You could slice the array */}
{customer.slice(0,5).map((c) => {
  return(
  <Table.Row key={c.id}>
    <Table.Cell>{c.name}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{c.address}</Table.Cell>
     <Table.Cell>
        <Button color="red">Delete</Button>
     </Table.Cell>
     <Table.Cell>
        <Button color="red">Edit</Button>
    </Table.Cell>
  </Table.Row>

)})}
        )

</Table.Body>
```

In case you evaluate the condition while iterate through the array:

```
<Table.Body > 
{customer.map((c, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) return null;

  return(
  <Table.Row key={c.id}>
    <Table.Cell>{c.name}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{c.address}</Table.Cell>
     <Table.Cell>
        <Button color="red">Delete</Button>
     </Table.Cell>
     <Table.Cell>
        <Button color="red">Edit</Button>
    </Table.Cell>
  </Table.Row>

)}).filter(Boolean)}

{/* Filter the return array from map */}

        )

</Table.Body>
```